# Always second row gets multiplied by number of rows

Tags: mysql

Asalamualikum!
Always the second row gets multiplied by the number of rows, If Any-one knows the solution please comment.

```
Select Medicine.MedicineID,Name, IFNULL(Sum(Purchase.Quantity),0) as TotalPurchase,
       IFNULL(Sum(Sale.SaleQuantity),0) as TotalSale, SUM(Purchase.Quantity-Sale.saleQuantity) as TotalRemainings
      from medicine 
      left Join Purchase ON Purchase.MedicineID=Medicine.MedicineID
      left Join Sale ON Sale.MedicineID=Medicine.MedicineID
      GROUP BY medicine.MedicineID
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Answer (score 1):

Joining happens *before* `GROUP BY`.  So, when there are multiple matches between the tables, `SUM()` will count the values multiple times.

The cure is to reformulate the query to *first* get the totals, *then* `JOIN`.

I am not clear on what is going on, but something like this:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT SUM(...) FROM Purchase ... GROUP BY ... ) AS p
    JOIN ( SELECT SUM(...) FROM Sale ...     GROUP BY ... ) AS s ON ...
```

If there could be zero rows, you may want `COALESCE(..., 0)`.

Comment: Thank You for Your Comment. it was a clue for me

Answer (score -1):

The Below Query worked for Me.

---

Select Medicine.MedicineID,Name, @pur:=(Select IFNULL(SUM(Purchase.Quantity),0) from Purchase Where Purchase.MedicineID=medicine.MedicineID) as TotalPurchase,
@sal:=(Select IFNULL(SUM(Sale.SaleQuantity),0) from Sale Where Sale.MedicineID=medicine.MedicineID) AS TotalSale,
@pur-@sal as TotalRemanings

from medicine
Left Join Purchase ON Purchase.MedicineID=medicine.MedicineID
Left Join Sale ON Sale.MedicineID=medicine.MedicineID
Group by Medicine.MedicineID

Comment: welcome to dba.se thanks for answering however, I am not sure that you query works honestly. can you add some evidence and explain?

Comment: The _setting_ of @variables in statements other than `SELECT` was recently deprecated in MySQL.